# Spring CSS image loading

Tags: java, css, spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring *3.0.7* for my web application. I want to load an image from my resource location in a CSS file like this:

```
.tag {
    background: transparent url(/resources/img/bg.gif) no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 50%;
    padding-left: 50px
}
```

I can easily load my static resource in jsp file as shown below without any issues:

```
<c:url value="/resources/css/main.css" />
```

My static resource handler has been configured as shown below:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/web-resources/"/>
```

As said ealier, I can load resources in jsp files without an issue, but cannot get the image to load in my CSS. Can anyone help load the image in the CSS file!

Comment: The image is not loaded?

Comment: I cannot get the image to load - yes!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If your folder tree is something like this:

```
+resources 
 -css
   -main.css

 -img
  -lots_of_img.jpg
```

Then is easier just to `url('../img/bg.gif')`.

Comment: It seems to be the only good solution and saves a lot of headache.

Answer (score 2):

The CSS path is relative to the CSS document location:

```
.tag {
    background: transparent url("resources/img/bg.gif") no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 50%;
    padding-left: 50px
}
```

**or**

```
.tag {
    background: transparent url("../resources/img/bg.gif") no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 50%;
    padding-left: 50px
}
```

**or based on the structure logic**

```
.tag {
    background: transparent url("../img/bg.gif") no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 50%;
    padding-left: 50px
}
```

**It all depends on your directory structure!**

You can read more about this [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-image) and [here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/background-image)!

Comment: Thanks Zuul - I have tried that but doesn't work neither. I think it is some how the way Spring is intercepting and translating the url.